# Prove or disprove $p\wedge(q\rightarrow r) \Longleftrightarrow (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$ using logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Here is what I have so far:

\begin{align*}
 p \wedge (q \to r)
   & \iff p\wedge(\neg q \vee r) 
\\ & \iff (p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge r) 
\\ &\iff \neg(p \to q) \vee (p \wedge r) 
\\ &\iff (p \to q) \to (p \wedge r) 
\\ &\iff (p \to q) \to r 
\end{align*}

Could someone please verify whether this is correct, and how to improve it?

Comment: You haven't actually *proved* what you want to prove, here. Your last line is an assertion, not a proof; if you justified it, that would make a proof.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thank you, that makes sense. Would it be complete if I added that, for example, if p=0 and r=1 (as suggested below), then p ∧ r = 0 and r = 1?

Comment: Yes, it's "obvious" that $a \to 0$ is not the same as $a \to 1$. For complete clarity it would be simplest also to provide a value of $q$ and state explicitly that under this valuation, one of the implications is $1$ and the other is $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a tautology, to disprove it, we only need to find a counter example.

Here we denote true as $1$, false as $0$.

Take $p=0,q=0,r=1$, then we have:

$$p ∧ (q → r) \equiv0\land(0\to1)\equiv0\land1\equiv0$$

$$(p → q) → r\equiv(0\to 0)\to1\equiv1\to1\equiv1$$

Since $1\neq0$, that '$p=0,q=0,r=1$' indeed is a counter example.

Hence this disproved the statement.